# How to wire a ceiling fan with lights, and a continuous wiring to spotlights

Tags: wiring

We want to install two separate ceiling fans with lights.  One room is fine, 3 wires go to fan, easily installed.  Separate are two spotlights (on a separate switch), they work fine too.
OUR ISSUE:  The other room has identical two separate switches, one to the original light fixture (that will change to a fan with lights), one switch to the spotlights.
Upon taking down the original light, we find we have 7 wires, (2 black; 2 white; 2 copper; 1 red).  Assuming we have the original light wires, and a continuous wiring to the spotlights.
The room that is fine, when we have bare wires to the light, the spotlights turn on independently.  However the other room, when we have bare wires to the light, the spotlights do not turn on independently.  Therefore, assuming to complete the circuit to the spotlights, wires from there and the light fixture (to be the fan and lights) is joined together???????
How can we wire all of this up.

RECAP:  Original light taken down, that was on a separate switch to the spotlights in the same room.  Now light taken down, and ready to insert a fan with lights, we have seven wires to contend with.  How do we wire these up?

So thankful for any information.
J.P.

Comment: You have bare wires to the light ? Maybe a picture of the wiring at the light and switches.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes please?